# Vite build not finding third-party exports

Tags: javascript, build, svelte, package.json, vite

I'm using vite/sveltekit and including a specific third party breaks my build but not my local version. What's the difference here ?

**Context** : I'm trying to include `svelte-tel-input` like this in my components:

```
  import { TelInput, normalizedCountries } from 'svelte-tel-input'
```

When I do this, `npm run dev` works fine but `npm run build` gives me this error : `EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read`

**Leads** : This looks like a path resolution problem, it's not resolving to the `index.js` file but to the directory, during build, thus the `EISDIR` error. But the weird thing is that event importing `svelte-tel-input/index.js` doesn't work. Only the absolute path to the index file seems to work.

I don't understand because my third-party library has this specified in his `package.json` :

```
"svelte" : ".",
  "license": "MIT",
  "exports": {
    "./package.json": "./package.json",
    ".": "./index.js"
  }
```

So why can `vite dev` resolve the path of the module but not `vite build` ?

PS : it works if I remove the `svelte: "."` attribute of the third party's `package.json` but that's not a fix, I don't have control on this file as it is a dependency.

Comment: Maybe the `"svelte" : "."` is wrong and should be reported to the package. Or Rollup (which should be used for the build) should be able to handle it but can't, then that should be reported there. Maybe it's the Svelte plugin for Rollup that has the issue...

Comment: Okay, thank's I'll try to do that. But Why should rollup be used ? Instead of Vite ?

Comment: I am not saying you should switch to Rollup but that Vite uses Rollup internally, [see docs](https://vitejs.dev/config/build-options.html#build-rollupoptions).

Comment: @antoinedavid Did you manage the problem ? I am the maintainer of the svelte-tel-input. Maybe I could help :).